How to show a maximum function is convex?
I know how to show that a differentiable function is convex. We can use the Hessian matrix, second derivative, and other techniques to demonstrate this. But how about for the maximum function?
I saw a book that uses Jensen’s inequality on $\max(\mathbb{E}[\text{some random variable})]$ and says the last term I wrote is smaller than $\mathbb{E}[\max(\text{some random variable})]$. Why is the maximum function convex, and how can we show this?
Reference: page 128 of the book "Bandit Algorithms,
Tor Lattimore,
DeepMind,
Csaba Szepesvári,
University of Alberta".

You should mention the book name with author name and the page number so that readers can track your question. It would be more better if you write the mathematics here.

@Learner I added the book name now

That sounds good. As you are a newcomer to this forum, you need to learn how to ask a good question. In the second paragraph of your question, you said "I saw in a book that uses Jensen's inequality....". Can you write those equations here? You just need use LaTeX. You can get an idea by looking at the other questions asked here. Just click download to download a brief introduction in LaTeX

The most useful technique is to show that the epigraph, in this case the set ${(t,x_1,\ldots,x_n)~:~t\geq \max{x_1,\ldots,x_n}}$ is convex, but it obviously is, since it is the intersection of convex half-spaces given by $t\geq x_1,\ldots,t\geq x_n$.

The most important technique you must always try when there're no obvious solutions is using the definition. For $0 \leq t \leq 1$ and vectors $x_1,x_2,$ we have
$$
\max(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) \leq \max(tx_1) + \max((1-t)x_2) = t\max(x_1) + (1-t)\max(x_2).
$$
This inequality is the definition of convexity and therefore the maximum function is convex.
